# Matching two column from one file to another

Tags: awk

How using `awk` code I can save the snp and `exons` only if `snp` column in my file `snp.csv`, falls within the `start` and `end` of the `exons.csv` file.

I would prefer to do this way.

For each value in `Snp` column

- Ignore all lines where `end`  is smaller than value in `Snp`
- When `end` is greater then `Snp`, check if `start` is smaller than `Snp`.
- If yes, for output, combine the matching lines from both data.frames

This is `snp.csv`

```
   Chr  Snp    Gene     
1   7 121851009 Gm15500 
2   7 121851032 Gm15500 
3   7 121851035 Gm15500 
4   7 121851036 Gm15500 
5   7 121851045 Gm15500 
6   7 121851081 Gm15500
```

I am trying to matching the above to `exons.csv`

```
  chr  start     end     
1 chr7 123268311 123268334
2 chr7 123272067 123272207 
3 chr7 123272905 123273039
```

`

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: Thanks @John1024 for the response. I did try in `R`. `coding_exons = sqldf("select * from snp left join exons on  snp.Snp between exons.start and exons.end")`. I am assuming it will be a shorter code in `awk`, but I have hardly any knowledge of it. So it does feel to me like asking for free consulting to me too.

Comment: Most important thing is what should be the index of the files? eg--> is it 1st line should be compared with first line of another file? or 1st line of first file should be compared with all the lines of another file? please confirm these all details in your post and here too.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. This is what I think I need.  • For each value in `Snp` column
 • Ignore all lines where `end`  is smaller than `Snp` column
 • When `end` is greater then `Snp` column, check is `start` column is smaller than `Snp`.
 • If yes, for output, combine the matching lines from both data.frames

Comment: @PDM, ok but how you want to compare it, from 1(column 1st of snp file) with 1(column 1st of exosn file) like that? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, preferable from line 1 of column 2 of snp file with all lines of column 2 and 3 of exons file. Does it still not make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since your samples are NOT clear specially expected output so based on your comments only this solution is:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR>1{start[FNR]=$3;end[FNR]=$4;next} FNR>1{for(i in start){if(end[i]>$3 && start[i]<$3){print}}}' exons.csv  snp.csv
```

If all conditions are meeting then line from snp.csv will be printed, if you want to print the lines from exons.csv then use following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR>1{complete[FNR]=$0;start[FNR]=$3;end[FNR]=$4;next} FNR>1{for(i in start){if(end[i]>$3 && start[i]<$3){print complete[i]}}}' exons.csv  snp.csv
```

Comment: @DOWN VOTER, would you bother to let me know the reason of down vote here?

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it works. Could you please explain how the code works. I am trying to understand 1) how `awk` is using if statement across two files. It is important for me to understand, so I know I am getting the right output.